# Jquery : href #hash not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, tabs, frontend

I have the following tab situation, **When i click on the tab it goes to its corresponding tab**, **but** the `URL` is not changing to `#foo` or `#bar`, I mean it should change to `abc.com/1#foo`

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left tabs" data-tabgroup="pet-details-group">
        <li><a href="#foo">Foooo</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#bar">Barrr</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="container no-padding tabgroup" id="pet-details-group">
    <div id="foo">
        Foooooo
    </div>
    <div id="bar">
        Barrrr
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the Jquery :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.tabgroup > div').hide();
    $('.tabgroup > div:first-of-type').show();
    $('.tabs a').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var $this = $(this),
                tabgroup = '#'+$this.parents('.tabs').data('tabgroup'),
                others = $this.closest('li').siblings().children('a'),
                target = $this.attr('href');
        others.removeClass('active_link');
        $this.addClass('active_link');
        $(tabgroup).children('div').hide();
        $(target).show();

    });
});
```

I don't know what am i missing.

Comment: The problem is: `e.preventDefault();`

Comment: @Ele Should i remove it ?

Comment: Yes, remove that

Comment: @Ele Okay the url is changing now, But when i paste the # url from another url, It does not show the corresponding tab.

Comment: Now you need to play with hash `window.location.hash` and programmatically change the tab.

Comment: your anchor tab is not closed

Comment: @gaetanoM Sorry my bad, But that markup is only for the question.

Comment: @Ele Okay should i redirect it to the # before everything.

Comment: No, you need to get that hash from `window.location.hash`, check if not empty and execute the logic to select the specific tab.  You need to extract that logic from the click handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay try out the following :

```
$('.tabgroup > div').hide();
    $('.tabgroup > div:first-of-type').show();
    $('.tabs a').click(function(e){
        var $this = $(this),
            tabgroup = '#'+$this.parents('.tabs').data('tabgroup'),
            others = $this.closest('li').siblings().children('a'),
            target = $this.attr('href');
        others.removeClass('active_link');
        $this.addClass('active_link');
        $(tabgroup).children('div').hide();
        $(target).show();
    }).filter('[href="' + location.hash + '"]').trigger('click');
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to take the value of the current `location.hash` (#foo, #bar, etc.) and use it to trigger tab selection on page load.

Something like this will do the trick:

```
$('.tabs a').click(function(e) {
  // ... no changes here
})
.filter('[href="' + location.hash + '"]')
.trigger('click')
```

So just add two new lines from above.